# PHP: compare objects inside of an array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I compare objects inside of an array?

I have a dynamically populated array of `simpleXML` objects (length is unknown)

Is there a fast way to compare all those objects inside the array and exclude duplicates?

And its getting a bit harder because ID field is different in every simpleXML object so I need to omit it in comparison.

For example simple short version:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ID] => 556
            [FIRST] => JOHN
            [MID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [LAST] => SMITH


        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [ID] => 557
            [FIRST] => JOHN
            [MID] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [LAST] => SMITH
        )

)
```

These are 2 duplicates. I need to confirm it and remove one.

**This is what i have so far:**

```
    $noDups = array();
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
    {
                    if (0 == $key) {
                         $noDups[] = $value;
                         continue;
                    }
        foreach($arr as $_key=>$_value)
        {

            $first = ( ((string)$value->FIRST) !== ((string)$_value->FIRST) )?true:false;
            $mid = ( ((string)$value->MID) !== ((string)$_value->MID) )?true:false;
            $last = ( ((string)$value->LAST) !== ((string)$_value->LAST) )?true:false;

            if ($first && $mid && $last)
            {
                array_push($noDups, $value);
            }
        }
    }
```

But i don't find this code `sexy` if you know what i mean.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I have tried manually going though array. Was wondering if there is s simpler solution. @JohnConde And, honestly, im on my 12th working hour question might be out of bounds haha

Comment: By "manually" i mean take each object in array and compare all its properties against properties in all other objects. But array might be huge. So im not sure.. at this point.. @JohnConde

Comment: I'm just curious, what happens to the "RECID" key in these duplicates above? will the second array contain just the "RECID" key, while the first remains the same?

Comment: @Charles oh sorry RECID doest exist. Just edited my question.

Comment: @RyanVincent i'm not sure i understand what you are trying to say. Did you try to ask something technical about my question? Could you re-phrase that please?

Comment: Sorry to bother you all, i misunderstood the issues. My mistake completely.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to delete duplicates from an array is [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function.

As stated in documentation, this function considers that two elements are equal if and only if their string representations are equal ( `(string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2` ).

The string represantion of objects can be handled by [`__toString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) magic method.

`SimpleXMLElement` already has [`__toString`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) implementation, so, in order to exclude ID from comparison, you need to override this method:

```
class ComparableXMLElement extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        //In order to exclude ID from comparison we need to return an unique string based only on specific attributes
        return md5("F".$this->FIRST."_M".$this->MID."_L".$this->LAST);
    }
}
```

Then you need populate your array with `ComparableXMLElement` objects instead of `SimpleXMLElement` and simple

```
$noDups = array_unique($arr);
```

will do the trick.

---

As a side note:

Since all comparison operators (e.g. !== ) already returns a boolean value, the use of ternary operator ( ? : ) is not necessary.
So instead of

```
$first = ( ((string)$value->FIRST) !== ((string)$_value->FIRST) )?true:false;
```

you should write

```
$first = ((string)$value->FIRST) !== ((string)$_value->FIRST);
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks and bout your side note: i know! its weird but thats what i did the first time but it doesnt work! try it: `$blah = ((string)'sd') !== ((string)'sd');` i think something is off because of the `(string)` conversion

Comment: @rinchik There is nothing wrong with `$blah = ((string)'sd') !== ((string)'sd');`. From [documentaion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php): ($a !== $b) returns TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type. In your case !== returns FALSE because 'sd' **is equal** to 'sd' =)

Comment: I understand that. Did you actually try in an action?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array and build an associative array with key = what matters

```
$uniq = array();
foreach($arr as $obj) {
  $uniq[$obj['FIRST'] . '::' . $obj['MID'] . '::' . $obj['LAST']] = $obj;
}
```